# Высота секций у landing page?

Tags: php, html, css

Есть ли какие то правила для высоты секций ?
Или советы от вас на тему, какой должна быть секция

Comment: разная! частенько используют full page

Comment: часто юзаю 100vh

Answer (score -2):

Обычно секцию делают равной высоте экрана браузера. Но чтобы было понятно, что нужно крутить мышь, дают визуальный маркер в виде вылезающего элемента или стрелки внизу экрана.

Comment: Тупо `height:100%;` для всех `section` или есть какой то определенный размер под большинство браузеров ?

Answer (score -2):

Тупо height можно использовать, если не париться с поддержкой разных браузеров.
А по уму высоту окна можно получить - document.documentElement.clientHeight

```
<button onclick="alert(document.documentElement.clientHeight)">Высота окна</button>
```